# Editable Combobox

Tags: user-interface, combobox, javafx

I have a singleton EmployeeDatabase that contains an ObservableList of employees.

This ObsList populates the contents of an editable combobox.

When a user selects one of the employees from the combo box and hits a button, I want that employee (from the database) to be displayed in a toString() in the console.

The problem is, the editable combobox does not let me select an employee directly. I'm supposed to use a StringConverter to turn that String into an Employee.

But the Employee already exists in the singleton database! Do I have to search for them in the database? Or is there an easier way to get the Employee as if the combobox weren't editable, and all I would have to do is cmbx.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()?

Comment: Do you override Employee.toString()?  Try that with a ComboBox<Employee>

Comment: Do you really want the `ComboBox` to be editable? What is the plan if they type something in that doesn't represent an Employee in the database?

Comment: If the Employee wasn't in the database, a popup will show asking them to add that "thing" into the database manually, Employee or not. (Asks for first name, last name, etc)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use a single control for multiple tasks, which doesn't necessarily make for the best user interaction. I would probably think about having a non-editable `ComboBox` and a button next to it called "Create new employee..." which opened the dialog. I'll answer the question as you have it stated though...

Comment: I do have a button that opens up the database for editing (adding, removal, etc.). I also agree with you that having a text field to enter in a new Employee directly is a strange idea. It's what my client wants though. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go back to the database, since you already have an `ObservableList` which contains the `Employee`s  that are in there. You should be able to do something like:

```
final ComboBox<Employee> employeeCombo = new ComboBox<>();
employeeCombo.setItems(EmployeeDatabase.getInstance().getEmployees());
employeeCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public Employee fromString(String string) {
        for (Employee employee : employeeCombo.getItems()) {
            if (string.equals(employee.getName())) { // may need more logic...
                return employee ;
            }
        }
        Employee employee = new Employee(string);

        // if things are set up correctly, this call should both update the database
        // and the observable list to which the combo box points
        EmployeeDatabase.getInstance().add(employee); 
        return employee ;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(Employee employee) {
        return employee == null : null ? employee.getName();
    }
});
employeeCombo.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: This assumes that all employees have a unique name. What if there are several with the same name? My employees each have a unique ID, but it makes no sense asking the user to enter in their ID to search for them.

Comment: Well, yes. So the only way this UI can possibly make sense is if the combo box is displaying a unique value for the employee. In that case, just adjust the code as needed. If the combo box is supposed to display the name, and names are non-unique, then there is simply no possible way to determine if the user intended to provide the name of an existing employee or a new employee with the same name. You need to have a discussion with the client in this case ;).

Comment: I probably will. Thanks a lot! I'm pretty sure this solution would work if I modified it to work with employee IDs, so have a freebie. :D

Comment: I suppose it may just be possible to show a dialog from the StringConverter code... let me experiment and maybe update...

Comment: No, that won't work. If the string displayed (or at least entered by the user) is non-unique, there's no way I can see to make it work the way you want.

Comment: I just went back to the regular combo box with a button for adding a new employee by hand. You're right, it's much more intuitive and doesn't require any guesswork. The only time I see an editable combo box being useful is if we were simply trying to store strings.